# In Skyrim, how can I keep my companion after getting married?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I got married in Skyrim, my companion ran away! When I tried to talk to her, all she said was, "congratulations on your wedding, I hope you two are happy together", in a tone in which you can sense she is hurt, deep down, that you did not choose her. She then proceeds to run way from you.

She even takes all your items! I was able to pickpocket my items back from her, but I want her to continue following me! How can I get her to continue following me after getting married? What console commands can I use to force her to continue following me?

Comment: I am using the latest version of Skyrim, 1.4.something.
Shortly before the wedding, I did put in the console codes to make her ready to marry me also. I wonder if that had something to do with it.
The Mod unfortunately does not surpass Lydia's running away. However, it does give me my second companion, and actually I like Muiri more anyway! Oddly, I was even able to get a third companion (not Lydia) by asking them to follow me. I think actually this is because in attempt to get Lydia back, I had put in the console code `set playerfollowercount 0` so that the game thought I had no followers.

Comment: Guess that's the downside of messing with the console commands.. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to get Lydia following me again, but I did just find a mod that lets me get another companion, just tried it and it works: [Skyrim Everplayer - Add Muiri As A Second Companion Even If You Are Married](http://www.everplexmedia.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=2041)

Comment: wait, the companion your speaking of is Lydia? I thought you couldn't marry Lydia? Why would she then be upset?

Comment: You CAN marry Lydia. I did on a previous game save. She seems a bit buggy with it though. Had to use a console command to reset her.

Comment: @Terry: bah. all these console commands. i play on xbox.

Comment: @Ender sorry to hear that.