# In Skyrim, I received a Letter of Inheritance from the courier, but it is blank! Is this a bug or is it supposed to be blank?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, after beginning the "Battle for Whiterun" and exiting the Palace of the Kings, the courier runs up to me and delivers a Letter of Inheritance. He says, "Here is a letter and a lot of gold - oh, and, sorry for your loss".

However, the letter is blank! All it says is "In the name of the Jarl" and nothing else. I feel like there should be more, but I can't be certain. I'm afraid that after the Lydia running away incident after I got married to someone else ([read my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50473/in-skyrim-how-can-i-keep-my-companion-after-getting-married) for more details), she seemed very emotionally unstable/upset, and that maybe when discovering that I had chosen to battle Whiterun, it was too much for her and she committed suicide! That would be terrible!

Is this a bug or is the letter supposed to be blank? Did Lydia commit suicide? I cannot figure out if there is supposed to be a mystery or if this is just a game bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is a bug. Normally it is sent by a follower, spouse, or other NPC you have befriended.

According to [the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Letter_of_Inheritance), it should contain this:

> <Character's name>, In the name of <Jarl's name>, it is with great
>   regret that we inform you of <NPC's name> death. The deceased has
>   bequeathed unto you a measure of inheritance in the amount of <number>
>   gold pieces.
>
> The Jarl's court has levied an amount of <number> gold pieces from the
>   sum, as the lawfully and honorably due tax. The remainder has been
>   commended unto the care of a trusted courier for deliverance.
>
> While all of the Jarl's court grieves with you on this day, we rejoice
>   in the knowledge that the deceased was in possession of dear friends
>   and wealth to communicate unto them.
>
> May this lawfully bestowed inheritance prove as a reminder of your
>   enduring faith in one another, and of the Jarl's beneficence accorded unto you both.